# Difference b/w val df = List(("amit","porwal")) and val df = List("amit","porwal")

Tags: scala

what is the difference b/w

```
val df = List(("amit","porwal"))
```

and

```
val df = List("amit","porwal")
```

My question is how 2 parenthesis are making a difference.Because On doing

```
scala > val df = List(("amit","porwal")).toDF("fname","lname")
```

it works, but on doing

```
scala > val df = List("amit","porwal").toDF("fname","lname")
```

scala throws me an error

> > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: 
> >         The number of columns doesn't match. Old column names (1): value New column names (2):
> >         fname,lname – 
> >         at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
> >         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.toDF(Dataset.scala:393)
> >         at org.apache.spark.sql.DatasetHolder.toDF(DatasetHolder.scala:44)
> >         ... 48 elided

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Tuple and List\[Any\] in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40904505/difference-between-tuple-and-listany-in-scala)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are different. The *paranthesis inside is treated as tuples by scala compiler*. Since there are two string values inside the nested brackets of your first example, it will be treated as `Tuple2(String, String)`. While the second example the string values inside the `List` are treated as *separate elements* as `String`.

*the first one* `val df = List(("amit","porwal"))` is `List[Tuple2(String, String)]`. There is *only one element in df* and to get *porwal* you have to do `df(0)._2`

And,

*the second one* `val df = List("amit","porwal")` is `List[String]`. There are *two elements in df* and to get *porwal* you have to do `df(1)`

Comment: On doing scala > val df = List(("amit","porwal")).toDF("fname","lname") it works, but on doing scala > val df = List("amit","porwal").toDF("fname","lname") scala throws me an error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match. Old column names (1): value New column names (2): fname, lname –

Comment: the answer clearly says that they are different. and the error message `The number of columns doesn't match. Old column names (1): value New column names (2): fname, lname` is clear enough I guess

Answer (score 1):

Even though the question is not related to spark

```
val df = List(("amit","porwal"))
```

Here df is `list` of `Tuple2`  as `List[(String, String)]`, To get the value `"amit"` you should use `df(0)._1` and for `"porwal"` `df(0)._2`

```
val df = List("amit","porwal")
```

Here is df is simply `list` of `String` as `List[String]`
In case of `List[String]` you can simply get as `df(0)` and `df(1)`

Hope this helps!

Comment: On doing scala > val df = List(("amit","porwal")).toDF("fname","lname") it works, but on doing scala > val df = List("amit","porwal").toDF("fname","lname") scala throws me an error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match. Old column names (1): value New column names (2): fname, lname – –

Comment: The error says clearly `The number of columns doesn't match` you have only one column which is a list of string as `List("amit","porwal")`  List("amit","porwal").toDF("fname") this should be used in your case.